# How do I clear the search in NEI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

As the title suggests, I waste so much time deleting what I've searched in the NEI search bar.

Is there a shortcut to clear the previous search so I can type a new query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the search bar will clear it.

From [ChickenBones' post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1279956-chickenbones-mods) on the Minecraft forum, under the section **Item Search Box**:

"Right clicking on the search box will clear it instantly"